# How to add id attribute with incremented number in Jquery or Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops, attributes

I have been trying for long to set an id attribute to the table row element of the table. Each time the loop finishes running I end up having the only id='9' on all the  tag. is there a way to increment the id attribute from 0 to 9, that is the first  tag get id='0' and the last gets id='8'.

```
$(function() {
    $('form').children().last().on('click', makeGrid)

    function makeGrid(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var height = $('#input_height').val();
        var width = $('#input_width').val();
        var color = $('#colorPicker').val();
        var pxheight = height + 'px';
        var pxwidth = width + 'px';

        for (var i = 0; i < height; i++) {
            $('table').append('<tr></tr>');
            $('tr').attr('id', i);
        }
        $('table').css({
            height: pxheight,
            width: pxwidth
        })
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just select that one element:

```
for(var i = 0; i < height; i++)
 $('table').append( $('<tr></tr>').attr('id', i) );
```

Comment: this worked for me. but i don't understand why you need to create a jquery object to achieve this

Comment: @deity that can be done with vanilla js as well. The main difference is that `$("tr")` selects all trs while everything we apply to `$("<tr></tr>")` just affects that created element